# How to create dynamic line chart with d3 with data from websocket?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying d3 for the very first time and I'm trying to understand how to create a dynamic d3 line chart that needs to get updated every time I receive a websocket message from the server with new a new data point.

I have the below code within my angular directive link function:

```
var data = [];
var margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d['label']); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d['value']); });

var svg = d3.select(elem[0])
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

Statistics.listen('topic', function(message) {
    data.push({
        label: message.webEvent.creationTimeStamp,
        value: +message.webEvent.value
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.label; }));
    y.domain([
        d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }),
        d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })
    ]);

    var svg = d3.select(elem[0]).transition();

    svg.select(".line")   // change the line
        .duration(0)
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
    svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
        .duration(0)
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
        .duration(0)
        .call(yAxis);
}
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of the "duration" is. The messages do not come through the socket at regular intervals. So I'm not sure if I should set a static duration value which I assume refreshes the graph based on the number given. I want the graph to update as and when I get an update. The graph, over time, should look like a running sine wave.

Right now, the first data that come gets rendered. But the graph stays static after that even though I can see incoming messages on the websocket and the data array is growing.

What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `duration` [is used in conjunction with transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) Also where is `elem` defined?

Comment: elem is the element parameter of the angular directive.
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {}

Comment: I would order my transitions slightly differently, might be personal preference but I would do `var svg = d3.select(elem[0]); svg.select(".line").transition().attr(...` and so on.

Comment: It sounds like your listen function is not selecting the svg element correctly -- you already have the `svg` variable defined outside of the listen function, so what happens if you comment out this line? `var svg = d3.select(elem[0]).transition();`